# How to add a button that is clickable when image is hovered over?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to add a button to my images when i hover over them so people can then visit another page. I have currently managed to add a darken on the image when it is hovered over but i want to add a button too. Any help would be appreciated. Have a good day

I have added a darken on hover but have no idea where to start on adding a button on hover

```css
    .insta div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .insta img{
     width: 88%;
     max-width: 100%;
     }
     .insta img:hover{
     -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 05s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="insta">
          <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="big1">
            <img src="insta/insta2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="big2">
            <img src="insta/insta3.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="big3">
            <img src="insta/insta4.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="big3">
            <img src="insta/insta5.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="big3">
            <img src="insta/insta6.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="big3">
            <img src="insta/insta7.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to be able to add a button that allows people to visit a different web page when hovered over the image

Answer (score 0):

For creating overlays, I would recommend using an element instead of `filter` due to its low browser support.

Below is a sample that i created to show you how it can be done. Basically a `div` (`.overlay`) is placed over the image and when the image parent is hovered, the overlay is shown. The button (and any other content) is added inside the overlay.

```css
.insta .wrapper{
    text-align:center;
}
.insta .wrapper .big {
    width:45%;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
}

.insta img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.insta .big .overlay{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .5s;
}

.insta .big .overlay .button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    width:30%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    background:#b39ddb;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:5px 15px;
}

.insta .big:hover .overlay{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="insta">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="big big1">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature/sepia?id=1">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="button">  
                Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="big big2">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature/sepia?id=2">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="button">   
                 Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="big big3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature/sepia?id=3">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="button">  
                 Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="big big3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature/sepia?id=4">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="button">
                 Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="big big3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature/sepia?id=5">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="button">  
                 Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="big big3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature/sepia?id=6">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="button">  
                 Button
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thankyou so much for this ! One last thing im wondering how i can make my photos appeare in a grid. I know i need to use a css grid to do this but cant get my head around it. If you wouldnt mind explaining that would be great ! Have a great day anyway !

Comment: @BenChesterman I would recommend using a plugin like [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) that can easily create image grids.

Comment: okay thankyou, Where is the href= for the buttons to link to where i want the buttons to lead

Comment: @BenChesterman To make the buttons links, replace the div (.button) with an anchor (a) element. Make sure to add the class `button` to it.